# React way to wait for the initialisation of a global function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have to use an old e-tracker script in my react app called [etracker](https://www.etracker.com/docs/).

To works, you have to include a `script` tag that will load the js sdk and will set some global functions:

```html
<head>
  <script
    id="_etLoader"
    type="text/javascript"
    data-secure-code="XXXXXX"
    src="//static.etracker.com/code/e.js"
  />
</head>
```

You can then use the global functions like `et_eC_Wrapper` to trigger some tracking events:

```js
et_eC_Wrapper({ et_et: 'XXXXXX', et_pagename: '/my-page-slug' })
```

The problem is that when I use this function, it could happen that `et_eC_Wrapper` is not set yet. Example in a `useEffect` hook:

```js
  React.useEffect(() => {
    try {
      console.log("success: ", et_eC_Wrapper);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("error:", error);
    }

    setTimeout(() => {
      try {
        console.log("success: ", et_eC_Wrapper);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log("error:", error);
      }
    }, 3000);
  }, []);
```

You will see in the console:

> error: ReferenceError: et_eC_Wrapper is not defined

> success: ƒ () {}

[image: Edit sad-wescoff-ldhb2]

I know that I could use a `setInterval` to check each seconds if the `et_eC_Wrapper` function is  set but is there a more 'React way' to handle it?

Comment: You can use [`useLayoutEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#uselayouteffect) to synchronously run after all DOM mutations.

Answer (score 1):

You can load `script` dynamically.

Put this code in the `component` where you want to use the `script`. Or if you want to use that script in more than 1 file then put this code somewhere in `App` or `Header` Component.

> Setting the `isScriptLoaded` to `true` once that `script` is loaded. You can then use this `isScriptLoaded` to render things that depend on the `script`.

```
const [isScriptLoaded, setIsScriptLoaded] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
    loadScript('script.js'); // your script url
}, [])


const loadScript = (src) => {
    let script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = src;    
    document.body.append(script);
    script.onload = () => { 
      setIsScriptLoaded(true); // setting flag true here
    };
}
```

Comment: Not really a React way to achieve that but it completely does the trick :+1: